# Manipulate Git repository with .net core

Tags: c#, .net, git, powershell, git-bash

I'm starting a new project at work and it basically needs to be able to add repositories to my database and keep track of it. Also download it and upload it to an api. later on be able to upload new files to the repo.

I know how to use C# and .Net core , is there any library to manipulate git?
Is it better to use another tool for the git part? maybe shell commands? (have never learned anything like that but open to it)

Anyway looking forward for recommendations on how to solve my problem, any insight/ experience is useful! 

I think the app will only connect to Github and Bitbucket at launch.

The connector should be able to 
1 keep track of a Repository. 
2 Download files changed in the repository. 
3 Upload them to another System (Non repo) 
4 The other system proccess the files 
5 Download new processed files from the System 
6 Upload them to the repository

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp)?

Answer (score 2):

Check https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp
You can query manipulate git repo with this library.

Comment: Thanks! will look into it! More importantly , im kind of a junior and use little to non git , do you feel its easier with bash+schedule or with .net and the lib?

Comment: Easier with the lib otherwise you will have to read all the doc of the git commands you plan to use to learn input options to format output text and interpret it!

Answer (score 0):

As I come to understand from your Question is that you want to push your DB to your git repository. So for that, you can't directly add your DB to the repository but there is a way you can add your SQL file to the git repository, for that follow below step: -

1. Need to create DB Project in your solution (right-click on your solution -> Add -> New Project -> SQL Server Database Project)
2. Click on `Tools` In Visual Studio menu -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparison
3. Select your target (target will be your database) -> select source (source will be the project you created)
4. Click on compare ->  you will see all you DB file
5. Click on Add button which DB file you want to add to Visual Studio
6. Update
7. Now your database file come to Visual Studio

This is the way, you can push you DB file to your Git repository.

I hope this will help you

Thank you

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain well, sory for that
What i need to make is a connector between GIT and another APP , where the connector has to keep track of the REPO files , when an update happens download the files changed and upload them to the APP. After a process , get the files back and upload them to the REPO.

Comment: Sorry still didn't get your Question, what do you mean by another app,
Do you want to create a repository in GIT and keep track of your code?

Comment: edit in question part